# "Sneaked off" vs "sneaked into" vs "sneaked away."

Tags: word-choice

I often get confused about which one to use. Example:

> He sneaked [...] to the rear of the ship.

Or maybe all of them have a different connotation?

Comment: Both *away* and *off* imply he left his current location and compatriots inconspicuously, without anyone noticing. By contrast, *into* means he got inside of the back of the ship without anyone noticing, likely because he wasn't supposed to be there. The former put emphasis on where he's *leaving*; the latter on where he's *arriving*. There is a subtle difference between *away* and *off*; the latter has a friendlier, more mischievous tint (perhaps he's headed for a secret tryst). The former has a stronger sense (though not absolute) of misconduct or transgression (e.g. escaping a prison).

Comment: But if you're going to be using the verb in a derogatory way (and there is very little other way to use it), the plural is _snuck_ in the US (there may be some confusion with _slunk_). I'd say _He snuck away_ (which indicates that there is a direction of sneakage) _to_ (to indicate that direction; if he reached it -- _towards_ if not) _the rear of the ship_. Also, if cover is involved, _snuck around to_ is OK. _Snuck off_ or _snuck away_, on the other hand, just mean leave in a sneaky way, any direction. You can _sneak into_ a closed space like a yard or a room. But only sneakily.

Comment: @JohnLawler Agreed, but don’t you mean that *snuck* is the past not the plural?

Comment: @tchrist: Whoops. Quite right, sorry. There are just too damn many grammatical terms that start with P. I blame the Romans.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Nah, it was those damn Phoneticians.

Comment: Yeah, but they spoke Sanskrit, and few of their terms start with P. _Parasmaipada_ is the only one I can think of right away.

Comment: @John Lawler, just for fun, I'm proposing a new/old past tense, 'snought'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Sneak](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sneak)* denotes stealthy movement:

> verb (past and past participle sneaked or informal , chiefly North
>   American snuck)
>
> 1 [NO OBJECT, WITH ADVERBIAL OF DIRECTION] Move or go in a furtive or
>   stealthy way:

Various directional adverbs can refine the sense of stealthy movement:

- In *He sneaked **away** to the rear of the ship,* *[away](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/away)* suggests motion **from** the point of reference--a literal or metaphorical distance:

> adverb
>
> 1.0 To or at a distance from a particular place or person:
>   *she landed badly, and crawled away*...
>
> 1.1 At a specified distance:
>   *when he was ten or twelve feet away he stopped*
>
> 1.2 At a specified future distance in time:
>   *the wedding is only weeks away*
>
> 1.3 Towards a lower level; downwards:
>   *in front of them the land fell away to the river*
>
> 1.4 Conceptually to one side, so as no longer to be the focus of attention:
>   *the Museum has shifted its emphasis away from research towards exhibitions*

- In *He sneaked **off** to the rear of the ship,* *[off](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/off)* also suggests motion **from** the point of reference:

> 1.0 away from the place in question; to or at a distance:
>   *the man ran off*
>
> 1.1 Away from the main route:
>   *turning off for Ripon*
>
> 3.0 Starting a journey or race; leaving:
>   *we’re off on holiday tomorrow*

- In *He sneaked **into** the rear of the ship,* *[into](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/into)* expresses motion **to enclosure**--literal or metaphorical:

> preposition
>
> 1.0 Expressing movement or action with the result that someone or something becomes enclosed or surrounded by something else:
>   *cover the bowl and put it into the fridge*
>
> 2.0 Expressing movement or action with the result that someone or something makes physical contact with something else:
>   *he crashed into a parked car*
>
> 3.0 Indicating a route by which someone or something may arrive at a particular destination:
>   *the narrow road which led down into the village*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*